# Simple equation for $x$ but getting no proof.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Show that there is at least one real value of $x$ for which
>
> $$x^{1/3} + x^{1/2} = 1$$

I did draw the graphs of $x^{1/3}$ and $1-x^{1/2}$ and showed that they met at a point, but I don't think it's a good algebraic proof.

How should I proceed after substituting $x$ for $z^{1/6}$ and getting a polynomial in terms of $z$

Comment: Please share your thoughts so far :)

Comment: okay. so i am posting a question and getting -2 votes and 0 answers. If someone thinks my question is too stupid shouldn't he or she drop by and give and answer too?

Comment: Have you seen the Intermediate Value Theorem?

Comment: It's not that your question is stupid. It's that you didn't show us what you tried.

Comment: It is to prevent a do-my-homework mentality...

Comment: No. this was a homework question on the chapter simple equations. I don't know any big mathematical theorems. i am finding it tough to write the functuions properly that is i am not getting the code

Comment: This isn't some website that does your homework; it's for improving your mathematical abilities. We'd rather help you help yourself :)

Comment: @AndréNicolas i checked out the intermediate value theorem. With that theorem it is pretty obvious. But what is the mathematical proof of that theorem?

Comment: *this was a homework question on the chapter simple equations* You could start by giving some context. Are you a high school student, an undergraduate college student, a graduate student (who needs to review some mathematics), an adult trying to review some math, . . .?? If this is for a course, what is the course? André Nicolas suggested the intermediate value theorem, but this would not be appropriate if the class is not calculus or higher. What is an example of a similar simpler problem in the course that you can solve (to get an idea of what level you're at)?

Comment: I am a high school student from India

Comment: A rigorous proof of the IVT is not easy. If this is a homework problem, and you have not met the IVT, I do not know what is expected.

Comment: If this is a non-rigorous high school algebra or precalculus question, you can simply draw rough sketches of $y = 1 - x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and $y = x^{\frac{1}{3}},$ and see that they clearly cross at one point. You should know what the graphs of a square root and a cube root look like, and to graph $y = 1 - x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ you can reflect $y = x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ about the $x$-axis (this gives the graph of $y = -x^{\frac{1}{2}}),$ and then shift the result vertically up by $1.$

Comment: Let $y = x^{1/6}$. Apply [Descrates rule of sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs) to the cubic polynomial $y^3 + y^2 - 1 = 0$, we find it has one positive root. This implies there is a positive $x = y^6$ that solves the original equation.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro i did plot the graphs but i dont think its a good proof as they are rough sketches

Comment: Note that I began my comment by explicitly specifying a content level (below the level of calculus) and by saying "non-rigorous". For U.S. algebra 2 and precalculus high school classes, the argument I gave would most likely be suitable. Unless you are more specific with what you know, I'm not sure how we can help. For example, have you studied any explicit methods (algebraic, trigonometric, hyperbolic, etc.) for solving cubic equations? Are you allowed to use the fact that any cubic polynomial has at least one real root? Can you use Descartes rule of signs?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Halves and thirds are expressible as sixths. $($This is what we get when bringing them both to a common denominator$)$. Let $x^{^\tfrac16}=t$, and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Consider the function:

$f(x)=x^{1/3}+x^{1/2}$

$f(0)=?$

$f(1)=?$

Comment: this is where the intermediate value theorem would come into play i guess

Comment: What about continuity?

Answer (score 0):

$$x^{1/3}+x^{1/2}=1\Leftrightarrow\,x^{1/6}(x^{1/6}+x^{2/6})=1\Leftrightarrow\,X(X+X^2)=1.$$
 where $X=x^{1/6}$.

So you have: $$P(X)=X^3+X^2-1=0.$$

See this polynomial, you will find out that it has one root. With some tests, I find out that this root is in the interval $[3/4, 1]$. Let call it $x_1$.

$x_1=x^{1/6}$. Hence the $x$ you are looking for is $x_1^{6}$.

Comment: There is a formula for the roots of a cubic polynomial (search Wikipedia, or ask Wolfram Alpha), but they are quite messy

Comment: The formula for the roots is pretty messy but it turns out the final answer for $x$ is reasonably simple $$\frac{1}{2916}\left(
\sqrt[3]{25 + 3\sqrt{69}} + \sqrt[3]{25 - 3\sqrt{69}} - \sqrt[3]{2}\right)^6 \sim 0.18503737524864$$